# How to decrease the space between the top margin and the chapter number box?

Tags: pdftex, chapters, sharelatex, overleaf

I am a beginner in using LaTex and I need some urgent help. I want to decrease the distance between the grey box(chapter number) and the top of the page in order to have more space in the beginning of each chapter but I can not seem to control that in the tex. file that I have attached below. Can you please assist me in knowing how I can decrease the distance that I am referring to?

```
% Chapter style (taken and slightly modified from Lars Madsen Memoir Chapter 
% Styles document
\usepackage{calc,soul,fourier}
\makeatletter 
\newlength\dlf@normtxtw 
\setlength\dlf@normtxtw{\textwidth} 
\newsavebox{\feline@chapter} 
\newcommand\feline@chapter@marker[1][4cm]{%
    \sbox\feline@chapter{% 
        \resizebox{!}{#1}{\fboxsep=1pt%
            \colorbox{gray}{\color{white}\thechapter}% 
        }}%
        \rotatebox{90}{% 
            \resizebox{%
                \heightof{\usebox{\feline@chapter}}+\depthof{\usebox{\feline@chapter}}}% 
            {!}{\scshape\so\@chapapp}}\quad%
            \vspace*{-1cm}
        \raisebox{\depthof{\usebox{\feline@chapter}}}{\usebox{\feline@chapter}}%
} 
\newcommand\feline@chm[1][4cm]{%
    \sbox\feline@chapter{\feline@chapter@marker[#1]}% 
    \makebox[0pt][c]{% aka \rlap
        \makebox[1cm][r]{\usebox\feline@chapter}%
    }}
\makechapterstyle{daleifmodif}{
    \renewcommand\chapnamefont{\normalfont\Large\scshape\raggedleft\so} 
    \renewcommand\chaptitlefont{\normalfont\Large\bfseries\scshape} 
    \renewcommand\chapternamenum{} \renewcommand\printchaptername{} 
    \renewcommand\printchapternum{\null\hfill\feline@chm[2.5cm]\par} 
    \renewcommand\afterchapternum{\par\vskip\midchapskip} 
    \renewcommand\printchaptertitle[1]{\color{gray}\chaptitlefont\raggedleft ##1\par}
} 
\makeatother 
\chapterstyle{daleifmodif}
```

[image: Picture of the distance I want to decrease]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a setting for `\beforechapskip`:

```latex
\makechapterstyle{daleifmodif}{%
    \setlength{\beforechapskip}{0pt}% adjust to suit (the default is 50pt)
    \renewcommand\chapnamefont{\normalfont\Large\scshape\raggedleft\so}%
    \renewcommand\chaptitlefont{\normalfont\Large\bfseries\scshape}%
    \renewcommand\chapternamenum{}%
    \renewcommand\printchaptername{} %
    \renewcommand\printchapternum{\null\hfill\feline@chm[2.5cm]\par}%
    \renewcommand\afterchapternum{\par\vskip\midchapskip}%
    \renewcommand\printchaptertitle[1]{\color{gray}\chaptitlefont\raggedleft ##1\par}%
}
```